# Angular Sidemenu subitems closes all together

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have Sidemenu in which i have items and subitems. What i need to do is open all subitems by default which is working but when i close it will just close that item only. Right now its closing all items together and on reopen its open that particular subitem which is fine but need to do same on close.

My html code

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!item.hidden">
  <li *ngIf="themeLayout === 'vertical'" data-username="dashboard Default Ecommerce CRM Analytics Crypto Project"
    class="nav-item pcoded-hasmenu ng-tns-c20-2 ng-star-inserted pcoded-trigger" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" href="javascript:" class="nav-link" (click)="navCollapse($event)">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemContent"></ng-container>
    </a>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="subMenuContent"></ng-container>
  </li>


  <ng-template #itemContent>
    <span class="pcoded-micon" *ngIf="item.icon">
      <i class="{{item.icon}}"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{item.title}}
      <span *ngIf="item.badge && themeLayout === 'horizontal'" class="badge label" [ngClass]="item.badge.type">
        {{item.badge.title}}
      </span>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="item.badge && themeLayout === 'vertical'" class="pcoded-badge label" [ngClass]="item.badge.type">
      {{item.badge.title}}
    </span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #subMenuContent>
    <ul class="pcoded-submenu" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of item.children">
        <app-nav-group *ngIf="item.type=='group'" [item]="item"></app-nav-group>
        <app-nav-collapse *ngIf="item.type=='collapse'" [item]="item"></app-nav-collapse>
        <app-nav-item *ngIf="item.type=='item'" [item]="item"></app-nav-item>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-collapse',
  templateUrl: './nav-collapse.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-collapse.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)', display: 'block'}),
        animate('250ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('250ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ],
})
export class NavCollapseComponent implements OnInit {
  public visible;
  @Input() item: NavigationItem;
  public dattaConfig: any;
  public themeLayout: string;

  constructor() {
    this.visible = false;
    this.dattaConfig = DattaConfig.config;
    this.themeLayout = this.dattaConfig['layout'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  navCollapse(e) {
    console.log('asddsa');
    this.visible = !this.visible;

    let parent = e.target;
    if (this.themeLayout === 'vertical') {
      parent = parent.parentElement;
    }

    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.pcoded-hasmenu');
    for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      if (sections[i] !== parent) {
        sections[i].classList.remove('pcoded-trigger');
      }
    }

    let first_parent = parent.parentElement;
    let pre_parent = parent.parentElement.parentElement;
      if (first_parent.classList.contains('pcoded-hasmenu')) {
        do {
          first_parent.classList.add('pcoded-trigger');
          // first_parent.parentElement.classList.toggle('pcoded-trigger');
          first_parent = first_parent.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        } while (first_parent.classList.contains('pcoded-hasmenu'));
      } else if (pre_parent.classList.contains('pcoded-submenu')) {
        do {
          pre_parent.parentElement.classList.add('pcoded-trigger');
          pre_parent = pre_parent.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        } while (pre_parent.classList.contains('pcoded-submenu'));
      }
      parent.classList.toggle('pcoded-trigger');
  }

}
```

Preview

[image]

Comment: Hi, did the second comment from Joosep.P fix your problem?

Comment: From the preview (very cool i didnt know we can do that here) it lools as if the menu is recreated that might be reason it behaves like that , can you check your ng if conditions one more time ? It might be forcing angular menu to get recreated, this is just a thought

Comment: Can you please upload your source code for this particular section and share the repository link as well? So we can check it in better way that where is the problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

The close event is bubbling to all menus. The simplest is to call stop propagation on an event handler.

On the event handler, we can there stop the propagation. Add this to your menu in html code:

```html
(click)="onEvent($event)"
```

To TS code:

```js
onEvent(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Or

```
(click)="navCollapse($event); event.stopPropagation();"
```

Comment: Tried not working.

Comment: Did you try `(click)="navCollapse($event); event.stopPropagation();"`?